# How to prove that a conditional pdf sums to 1?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $p(x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1]$ and $p(y): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1]$ be two probability density functions (pdf) with joint distribution $p(x,y): \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow [0,1]$. Consider the conditional pdf of $y$ given $x$, defined as:
\begin{equation}
p(y|x) = \begin{cases} \frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)},\text{ if }p(x) \neq 0 \\
0,\text{ if } p(x)=0\end{cases} 
\end{equation}

My question is how to prove that $p(y|x)$ is such that

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(y|x) dy = 1 \text{  } \forall x
\end{equation}

I had some ideas, but unfortunately they are apparently useless. Please let me share my thoughts:

Because $p(x)$ and $p(x,y)$ are pdf, the respective integrals over their entire domains equal 1 and, from the definition of $p(y|x)$, it follows that $p(x,y) = p(y|x)p(x)$. Using this equality in

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x,y) dx \text{ }dy = 1
\end{equation}

leads to

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x) \int_{-\infty}^\infty p(y|x) dy \text{ }dx = 1
\end{equation}

Now, since the integral of $p(x)$ equals 1, it would be enough to prove that the function $f(x)$, defined as

\begin{equation}
f(x) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(y|x) dy ,
\end{equation}

is constant. I tried to prove this by contradiction, but unfortunately I came to no conclusion.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: One might mention that overloading a given notation with several different meanings cannot help one's understanding of the corresponding setting. Here one could use $p$ for the first marginal and $q$ for the second marginal. In formulas, $$p(x)=\int p(x,y)dy\qquad q(y)=\int p(x,y)dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider the connection between $p(x)$ and $p(x, y)$, i.e. $p(x) = \int p(x, y) \, dy$. This immediately yields $\int p(y|x) \, dy = 1$ for all $x$ with $p(x) \ne 0$.

Comment: Great, thank you! That was rather obvious, shame on me :p